# RxJS Type signature of EMPTY observable?

Tags: rxjs

What is the type signature of an empty observable?

Consider the following example. The first stream in the `concat` below emits no values and eventually completes. How would I lets typescript know that `emptyOf` returns an observable that doesn't emit any values?

```js
function emptyOf(stream$: Observable<any>): Observable</*empty ?*/> {
  return stream$.pipe(filter(_ => false));
}

concat(
  emptyOf(pageLoadingStages$),
  welcomeMessage$
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try `Observable<never>`, got the idea from [`EMPTY`'s implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/empty.ts#L28)

```js
export const EMPTY = new Observable<never>(subscriber => subscriber.complete());
```

Comment: I didn't know that 'never' was a type in Javascript. Very cool. Thanks

Comment: @MrkSef in JavaScript there are no types, TypeScript is what makes it possible.